# React, 404 not found on password request update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern

I am trying to learn nodejs and react with mongodb. I have setup what I know is (sketchy) but a so far working login, signup, and password reset system. Currently with the password reset system one the user recieves the email and tries to update there password. I get a 404 not found. I have tried multiple different combinations of ways I can think of, looked at other stack over flow questions, visted a youtube tutorial and asked chatgpt who had a stroke.

**Reset password function from auth controller:**

```
export const resetPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token2 = crypto
      .createHash("sha256")
      .update(req.params.token2)
      .digest("hex");
    const user = await User.findOne({
      passwordResetToken: token2,
      passwordResetTokenExpires: { $gt: Date.now() },
    });

    if (!user) {
      return next(errorHandler(401, "Token wrong or invalid!"));
    }

    const newPassword = req.body.password;
    const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(newPassword, 10);
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
    user.passwordResetTokenExpires = undefined;

    user.save();

    const logintokeen = signToken(User._id);

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      token: logintokeen,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**Router Code:**

```
router.post("/signup", signup);
router.post("/signin", signin);
router.post("/google", google);
router.get("/signout", signout);
router.post("/forgotPassword", forgotPassword);
router.patch("/resetPassword/:token2", resetPassword);
router.post("/newpassword/:token2", resetPassword);
export default router;
```

**Newpassword page**

```
export default function Newpassword() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { token2 } = useParams();
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
      const res = await fetch(`/resetPassword/:token2`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ hashedPassword }),
      });
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${res.status}`);
      }
      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.success === false) {
        console.log("failed");
        return;
      }
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Enter Your new Password</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">New password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Enter your new password"
            className="bg-slate-100 p-3 rounded-lg"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.js code:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* header */}
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/forgotpassword2" element={<Forgotpassword2 />} />
          <Route path="/newpassword/:token2" element={<Newpassword />} />
          <Route path="/resetpassword/:token2" element={<Newpassword />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any route matching the `resetPassword` `post` request on the backend. The resetPassword route present in the backend is of method patch. But you are making a post request from the frontend. Try changing the method type from `post` to `patch` on the frontend. Also the body contains `hashedPassword` as the key name but you are using `password` on the backend to get the value.
`const newPassword = req.body.password;`
this should be
`const newPassword = req.body.hashedPassword;`

If you are sending some token in the url as params
`/resetPassword/token2`
change it to `/resetPassword/${token2}` on the frontend to use the value in token2 in string literal.